# What op-amp can I use in this output filter recommended design?

Tags: operational-amplifier, audio, impedance, dac, active-filter

I'm working with the [Cirrus Logic CS42448 codec](https://www.cirrus.com/products/cs42448/) and would like to implement an active filter output to differential audio signals.

The output should be line level to be connected directly to external audio amplifiers or active speakers. Do I have to change the component values if I use a NE5532? I'm still learning how to calculate impedance. Do I also need to have another op-amp as a buffer to control that? What do you suggest?

Finally, is this recommendation taking differential signals but outputting as single-ended? What I'm looking for should output differential signals, can I still achieve that with this circuitry somehow?

Thanks!

[image: recommended active filter on CS42448 datasheet]

Image source: [Cirrus Logic - CS42448 datasheet](https://statics.cirrus.com/pubs/proDatasheet/CS42448_F5.pdf)

Comment: The NE5532 would be a wonderful choice for this application. Just make sure you use bipolar supplies for the opamp.